# doctrine-odm how to map a json to a filed

Tags: json, mongodb, doctrine-orm, mapping, doctrine-odm

I would to map to a class an object stored into a mongodb collection with rows like this:

```
{ 
  "locale":"en_US", 
  "dictionary":
    {
     "key1":"value1",
     "key2":"value2"
     ...
    }
}
```

how can I map this to a class?
which kind of type field I have to use?

```
/** @ODM\Document(collection="Dictionary")
class Dictionary extends Bean {

    /** @ODM\Field(type="string") */
    public $locale;

    /** @ODM\Field(type="??????") */
    public $dictionary;

}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is key value pairs then [hash](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#hash) will be sufficient.

```
/** @ODM\Field(type="hash") */
public $dictionary;
```